# Mail Merger Speed Up

Tags: email, microsoft-word, speed, merge, recipient

I have a list of names and addresses in a word file on my computer. In order to use Microsoft Word's Mail Merge I have to have those names and addresses in a recipient list. I go to create a recipient list and it seems like I have to enter each name and address in again individually. Is there any way to speed up this process because I have a few hundred names and it would be a serious pain to type all of them in individually.

Comment: if the answer below does not answer your question, comments would be helpful. In addition, it is polite to mark as the answer the post that answers your question (the check mark next to the answer). Welcome to Superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have always done this in excel, but in word it's [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/mail-merge-step-2-connect-to-a-data-file-and-select-records-HA001109550.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001109549), and for directions in excel its [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/print-labels-by-using-excel-data-in-a-word-mail-merge-HP005203760.aspx). They do a good job of giving instructions, but its long, so I will not reproduce the whole thing here.